# Incorporating JavaScript in HTML

Tags: javascript

I am new in HTML writing via dreamweaver 2020.

I have added the following codes to dw:-

```
<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>The ul, ol, and li tags</title>
        <style type="text/css"> body {background-color: #E4E978;}</style>
        <script type = "text/javascript">;
            today = new Date();
            dateValue = today.getYear() + "午" + today.getMonth() + "月" + today.getDay() + "日";
            window.alert("\n welcome \n\n today is " + dateValue "\n\n redirecting to my site");
            var hour, min;
            function showclock();
                {   now = new Date();
                    hour = now.getHours();
                    if (hour <=9) hour = "0" + hour;
                    min = now.getMinutes();
                    if (min <= 9) min = "0" + min;
                    document.clock.time.value "NOW is" + hour + "/" + min;
                    setTimeout("showclock()", 1000 );
                }
        </script>
    </head
```

I found that they were totally ignored.

Other things that I have tried (and with the same being-ignored result) are:-

(1) Use `<script language = "JavaScript">` instead;

(2) adding `<!--` in case some browsers have no JavaScript interpretation power;

(3) running on different engines (edge etc.)

Please let me know what procedures that I have missed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you [open the JavaScript console](https://support.cytobank.org/hc/en-us/articles/206273618-How-to-open-and-use-your-browser-s-JavaScript-console) in your browser when loading the page, you'll see that the JavaScript code has a parse error, which prevents the browser from loading the script at all.  This is why it seems to be ignored.

Here is a version without parse errors:

```html
<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>The ul, ol, and li tags</title>
        <style type="text/css"> body {background-color: #E4E978;}</style>
        <script type = "text/javascript">;
            today = new Date();
            dateValue = today.getYear() + "午" + today.getMonth() + "月" + today.getDay() + "日";
            window.alert("\n welcome \n\n today is " + dateValue + "\n\n redirecting to my site");
            var hour, min;
            function showclock()
                {   now = new Date();
                    hour = now.getHours();
                    if (hour <=9) hour = "0" + hour;
                    min = now.getMinutes();
                    if (min <= 9) min = "0" + min;
                    document.clock.time.value = "NOW is" + hour + "/" + min;
                    setTimeout("showclock()", 1000 );
                }
        </script>
    </head>
```

However, the function `showclock()` is never called by this code; perhaps you meant to call it?

`setTimeout("showclock()", 1000 );` uses very old and discouraged syntax.  It would be better replaced with `setTimeout(showclock, 1000);`

`document.clock.time.value` doesn't work as is.  Perhaps you mean something like `document.querySelector('.clock .time').value`? There's currently nothing in your DOM so it's difficult to guess.

Comment: thanks for the advice. Will try the suggestions mentioned.